# How can I make a form in php that allows the user to add additional form fields if they need them?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that has multiple fileds that are the same, example: 
QTY  Part Number  Manufacture  Price  and below these would be 5 rows, I want to reduce that to 1 row and give the user the option to add additional rows with multiple columns if they need to. Is this something that has to be done with JavaScript? can I have something like a small button, click here to add an additional row?

I tried this but it doesn't add any fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>More form fields</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            FUNCTION addRowToTable()
            {
            VAR tbl = document.getElementById('tblAddress');
                    VAR lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                    // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
                    VAR iteration = lastRow;
                    //  var iteration = lastRow + 1;
                    VAR row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
                    //  cell 0
                    VAR cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
                    VAR el = document.createElement('input');
                    el.type = 'text';
                    el.NAME = 'Address[]';
                    el.size = 30;
                    cell0.appendChild(el);
                    //cell 1
                    VAR cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
                    VAR el = document.createElement('input');
                    el.type = 'text';
                    el.NAME = 'City[]';
                    el.size = 10;
                    cell1.appendChild(el);
                    //cell 2
                    VAR cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
                    VAR el = document.createElement('input');
                    el.type = 'text';
                    el.NAME = 'State[]';
                    el.size = 2;
                    cell2.appendChild(el);
                    //cell 3
                    VAR cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
                    VAR el = document.createElement('input');
                    el.type = 'text';
                    el.NAME = 'Zip[]';
                    el.size = 5;
                    cell3.appendChild(el);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Dynamic add form fields</h3>

        <form action="Untitled-2.php" name="h" method="post">
            <table id="tblAddress">
                <tr>
                    <td class="txtBase">Address</td>
                    <td class="txtBase">City</td>
                    <td class="txtBase">State</td>
                    <td class="txtBase">Zip</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="Address[]" type="text" size="30" maxlength="255"></td>
                    <td><input name="City[]" type="text" size="10" maxlength="255"></td>
                    <td><input name="State[]" type="text" size="2" maxlength="10"></td>
                    <td><input name="Zip[]" type="text" size="5" maxlength="25"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add" onClick="addRowToTable();"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use JS to add more rows, and then setup your PHP to accommodate X amount of rows for processing.

Comment: yes, to keep it simple you have to do it using js. just add a function which would create elements dynamically based on the specified number and associate it a button click event. make sure you assign a different id for each of the elements,so that it will be easy to process them individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly less verbose version using jQuery > 1.7 and it's preferred on() method for event binding:

http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/5077/

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
</form>
<button id="addFields">Add another field</button>

<script>

$(function ($) {

    $('body').on("click", '#addFields', function () {
        $('form').append('<input type="text" />');
    })

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but when I click the button it doesn't add another field, same with vector's script as well and the script I posted in my question.

Comment: Do you have Javascript disabled?

Comment: Also if you're copying this into your project, you'll need at add a <script> tag linking to jQuery > 1.7 in the HEAD.

Comment: If you run into problems like this with Javascript, just whip open the Javascript console (in Chrome, or download Firefox's firebug) and it will tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: no JavaScript isn't disabled I use it to calculate the totals in my form so I know it's working in the browser, I just tried what you suggested in firefox and nothing happens, no errors in firebug

Comment: my bad, every time I click the button to add a new field in the script above it adds an error to firebug but I can't see where the error is at. give me a minute I'll upload it to a server

Comment: For a start change all your javascript keywords to lowercase. function instead of FUNCTION etc

Comment: Then make sure the function is defined in the scope you're calling it. Or add it to the window object: http://jsfiddle.net/69Fvp/

Comment: Or here's a more object oriented approach if you're planning on adding more functionality to the table later or having multiple tables: http://jsfiddle.net/FyqwC/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31026/discussion-between-jason-and-matt-harrison)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it with javascript OR php.

Javascript is faster and better in all ways, also it does not touch the server every time you need to add a field.

Php requires a page refresh every time you need to add a field and is done server-side, which will increase the load on your servers. You simply need to rebuild the form every time a field needs to be added or removed. Don't forget to re-populate the already filled form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do this...

```
<div id="pricecontainer"></div>
 <a id="addprice" href="javascript::void(0)">Add More</a>


 <script>
 $('#addprice').click(function(){
           $len= $("#pricecontainer").children("div").length;
           $("#pricecontainer").append("<div class='FormWrap PriceBorder' id='"+$len+"'><div class='input text'><label>Price</label><input style='width: 100px;' class='price' type='text' name='price[]' id='price"+$len+"' maxlength='5'></div></div>");

        }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: $len= $("#pricecontainer").children("div").length; it will count the child of div appended in price container.